# Access an object returned from the database with Javascript MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

How do I access an object returned from the database with Javascript

This function is called from Javascript

```
function searchUser() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('UserName').value
    $.post("SearchForUser", { userName: userName }, function (UserInfo) {

        UserInfo; //How to access the returned UserInfo properties?

    });
}
```

I Use this code to get the UserInfo from the database

```
    public UserInfo SearchForUser(string userName)
    {
       string password = "nicola";

        using (FormValueEntities db = new FormValueEntities())
        {
            //Query the database for the user
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
            userInfo = db.UserGet(userName, password).FirstOrDefault();
            return userInfo;
        }
    }
```

The UserInfo has the Following properties : UserName, UserPassword and Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better if you returned a `JsonResult`

```
public JsonResult SearchForUser(string userName)
{
     ...
     return Json(userInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     //you don't need the AllowGet if this is a POST action, cannot tell
}
```

Then in JavaScript you can have easy access to your model, e.g.

```
$.post("SearchForUser", { userName: userName }, function (UserInfo) {

        console.log(UserInfo.UserName) ; 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your action return from the method [Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) . This will JSON-serialize the object you give it and return a `JsonResult`.

```
public ActionResult Search(string usernameName)
{
    return Json(SearchForUser(userName)); // borrows the result of your SearchForUser method and returns it as JSON-serialized string.
}
```

`JsonResult` should set the response content type to "application/json", so that means that jQuery's `$.post` should see that response header and automatically deserialize it.

```
function searchUser() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('UserName').value
    $.post("Search", { userName: userName }, function (UserInfo) {

        alert(UserInfo.Description); // example of consuming the deserialized JSON messsage.

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your script is server side Java I assume.

You can't just return it like that, what jQuery does is make a http request to the server and the server will then send a response back.

As dove commented you can format your response as JSON and use the jQuery.getJSON on the client side.